# API Manager throws error when trying to view api statistics

Tags: api, wso2

I am trying to integrate the BAM Server(2.4.0) and API Management(1.6) getting error:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2014-04-11 08:45:17,838] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error
>   while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException:
>   BAM data source hasn't been initialized. Ensure that the data source
>   is properly configured in the APIUsageTracker configuration.  at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryFirstAccess(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1693)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.getFirstAccessTime(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1675)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getFirstAccessTime(APIProviderHostObject.java:2911)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

My data source is defined as

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:h2:C:/esb/wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
            <username>wso2carbon</username>
            <password>wso2carbon</password>
            <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
 </datasource>
```

Also, I noticed BAM server throws following error afterwards

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation} - 
>   Failed to write data to database org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL
>   not allowed for column "CONSUMERKEY"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO
>   API_REQUEST_SUMMARY
>   (version,consumerkey,max_request_time,api_version,time,hostname,context,day,year,month,total_request_count,userid,apip
>   ublisher,api) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [90006-140]

I have followed the instruction on 
https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[api-manager.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Dp1mbqiC69WWNNV1BQNm9vdVU/edit?usp=sharing)

[master-datasource.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Dp1mbqiC69M3MtTkp4UmstTlk/edit?usp=sharing)

[Hive job log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Dp1mbqiC69QVFYeWJwTjZic1U/edit?usp=sharing)

[wso2carbonlog.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Dp1mbqiC69azE0M2N0dlJCaWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is there because of adding consumerKey as null in to the database. This has been fixed in API manager 2.0.0. You can find the related [JIRA ticket APIMANAGER-2032](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2032) for this issue.

To fix this issue, you need to modify the API manager stats analyzer hive script that you can find in your BAM instance. Open it and edit the following insert query. Then AM will add the empty string as 'anonymous' which is the expected value(COALESCE(consumerKey,'')).

```
insert overwrite table APIRequestSummaryData select api, api_version,version, apiPublisher, COALESCE(consumerKey,''),userId,context,max(requestTime) as max_request_time,sum(request) as total_request_count,hostName, year(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )) as year, month(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )) as month,day(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )) as day,concat(substring(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),0,16),':00') as time from APIRequestData group by api,api_version,version,apiPublisher,consumerKey,userId,context,hostName,year(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )), month(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )),day(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )),hour(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )),minute(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' )),substring(from_unixtime(cast(requestTime/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),0,16);
```

Likewise, modify all the `insert` queries in the hive script where it tries to write the `consumerKey`. The structure is almost the same across all the queries, so it should not be hard to change.

Comment: Thanks Kusan. Do you know name of the script and folder location? I can't find it.

Comment: The file name is `am_stats_analyzer` and is located in BAM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/bam-toolbox/API_Manager_Analytics.tbox. But since you have already uploaded your toolbox, it's better if you can modify it by logging into your BAM instance. In the BAM mgt console, go to `Analytics -> List`, and edit the `am_stats_analyzer_xxx` script. See the [screenshot](https://docs.wso2.org/download/attachments/30540983/list-analytics.png?version=1&modificationDate=1376816429000)

Comment: Thanks again. The change solved the second error with inserting data when authentication is disabled. The first error still remains. Not able to view BAM statistics. I tried to clean up the database and recreated users, apis, subscriptions but still the same error - BAM data source hasn't been initialized. Ensure that the data source is properly configured in the APIUsageTracker configuration. Thanks for  your help.

Comment: Did you make sure that BAM succeeds in storing the stats in your WSO2AM_STATS_DB? To understand why APIM is not able to read from the DB, can you attach the `api-manager.xml` and the `master-datasources.xml` of your APIM instance? I suspect your first issue is because of a config error. (You might want to remove sensitive data if required from conf files.)

Comment: I checked through BAM console that data is being populated in APIRequestData and APIResponseData tables. All other tables listed in am_stats_analyzer_xxx scripts are empty. Both configuration files have been attached to my original post

Comment: Any other feedback? I was hoping to demo it next Tuesday. Thanks.

Comment: I just had a look at the api-manager.xml. It seems you didn't set the `<DataSourceName>` under `<APIUsageTracking>`. APIM looks for BAM statistics in that DB. You can simply uncomment, and restart APIM, since you have defined the datasource with the default name, 'jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB', in your master-datasources.xml.

Comment: Still APIM wouldn't be able to read any statistics since the DB is empty as per your last comment. This means that BAM somehow is failing to publish data. May be the `am_stats_analyzer_xxx` hive script isn't running. (did you schedule it?) What does the BAM logs say? If the script is running it should print loads of logs. Were there any errors?

Comment: yes, I am seeing the page but it doesn't show the statistics. I have attached BAM log files. Based on the log files, there is a job running but I am not sure if there is a different job to populate summary tables. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am going to mark this question answered (in its original context) and open a new thread for database tables not being populated.

Comment: This COALESCE is necessary in multiple places in the hive script, for example for the fault summary insert query also.